# Hide input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/rEPXM/23/

I'd like to know how I can hide that <kbd>Add</kbd> submit button until I click the <kbd>+</kbd> image to add input boxes to the form.

I don't want to add the submit button next to the input box because I want to be able to add multiple input boxes and submit them all when I click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">      
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxtitle"><span class="boxtitleleftgap">&nbsp;</span><span class="boxtitlebulk"><span class="boxtitletext">Folders</span><div style="float: right; margin-top: 4px;"><a href="#" onclick="javascript: AddFolder();"><div class="addplus">&nbsp;</div></a></div></span></div>
      <div class="boxcontent">
        <form method="post" id="folderform" action="page.php?action=list-volunteer-apps" name="folderform">
          <a class="even" href="page.php?action=list-volunteer-apps&folder=2">Folder 2 <span class="text">(1)</span></a><a class="even" href="page.php?action=list-volunteer-apps&folder=1">Folder 1 <span class="text">(0)</span></a>
          <div id="foldercontainer"><input type="submit" value="Add"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function AddFolder() {
    $('#foldercontainer').append('<input name="folder[]" type="text" size="20" />');
}​
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just give the button an ID, and make it start hidden

```
<input type="submit" id="addButton" value="Add" style="display: none;">
```

Then use the `show()` jQuery method:

```
$("#addButton").show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TcFhy/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you could do this... also, cleaned up the method used for making these input boxes a bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/4JANS/

So, in your html you might have:

```
  <div id="foldercontainer">
      <input id="addSubmit" type="submit" value="Add">
      <input id="folderName" name="folder[]" type="text" size="20" style="" />
  </div>
```

and your CSS might be:

```
#foldercontainer #addSubmit {
    display:none;
}
#foldercontainer #folderName {
    display:none;
    width: 120px; 
    background: #FFF url(http://oi47.tinypic.com/2r2lqp2.jpg) repeat-x top left; 
    color: #000; 
    border: 1px solid #cdc2ab; 
    padding: 2px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and your script could be:

```
// set up a variable to test if the add area is visible
// and another to keep count of the add-folder text boxes
var is_vis = false,
    folderAddCt = 0;

function AddFolder() {
    if(is_vis == false){
        // if it's not visible, show the input boxes and 
        $('#foldercontainer input').show();
        // set the flag true
        is_vis = true;
    } else {
        // if visible, create a clone of the first add-folder
        // text box with the .clone() method
        $folderTB = $("#folderName").clone();
        // give it a unique ID
        $folderTB.attr("id","folderName_" + folderAddCt++);
        // and append it to the container
        $("#foldercontainer").append($folderTB);
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the button out of the folder wrap, and I am showing it when you add a new folder. This way the button will stay at the bottom when adding new folders. I also removed the inline style, and replaced it with a class.

This is used to display the button, just add it to the `AddFolder()` function:

```
$('#addBtn').show();
```

I am hiding it with CSS like this:

```
#addBtn { display: none;}
```

I moved the button out of the `#foldercontainer`, this way it will always stay at the bottom when you add multiple folders, as you wanted:

```
<div id="foldercontainer"></div>
<input id="addBtn" type="submit" value="Add">
```

Look here for the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmx4Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form#folderform input[type=submit]').hide();
```

Then show the add button after you click the submit

http://jsfiddle.net/SQh8L/