# Hide button until we upload image or text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

we have a button "**save design**" in [page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4s.html) also we have option to upload image or text in the page.
until **user upload image or Add text**, we dont want to display button "save design"

[image]

we are using below code for "save design"

```
_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >SAVE DESIGN</button>' +
                '<button >Reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },


    initObservers: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
            $('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));
        }
    },

    submitApply: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.apply();
    },
```

I tried below code to hide the "save design" until we upload image or text.
i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051460/hide-input-button)  i added `style="display: none;` and than used  `show() jQuery` method.

```
<script>
    $('submit-editorApply-').show();
    _getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" style="display:none;" >SAVE DESIGN</button>' +
                '<button >Reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

</script>
```

Comment: the save design button is not visible

Comment: @SagarV i am working on that, give me a min, i will revert my changes.....

Comment: Ok. ping me once you completed.

Comment: are you working on it again?

Comment: @SagarV sorry, give me some more time.....

Comment: in which you are using ajax? jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139730/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-sagar-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ajax to upload and apply image/text on svg simplly call  `jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show();` on that ajax's success(its may be the most easy way if u are using ajax).

Comment: I tried as `submitApply: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.apply();
  jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show();
    },` but it didt worked for me.... please tell what wrong i am doing......

Comment: for that u need to write function on delete image/text that is any other element is on canvas or not and if not then hide the button again.

Answer (score 3):

Attach an event listener to those two input fields, which then checks if the field is filled. Only then you use `$('#submit-editorApply-').show();`.

Example:

```
$('#upload_field').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
        $('#submit-editorApply-').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do the same thing when text is removed: simply check if there still is an image and/or text. If that's not the case, use `.hide()`

Answer (score 2):

Provide a `display: none;` to your `#aitcg-control-panel` so that it is hidden on initial load.

```
#aitcg-control-panel {
  display: none;
}
```

Then you have to check if the file upload is successful without any error, and then show the *Save design* button.

```
jQuery('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
   if(jQuery(this).val()) {
      jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show();
   }
});
```

**EDIT**

To hide the *SAVE DESIGN* button, add the following code:

```
jQuery("svg text tspan").on("click", function() {
  if(jQuery(this).html() === "x") {
     jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Now it hide the `save design` button, but not displaying after we upload image or text.....

Comment: is we need to use dynamic values here : `#add_image_1669316654` ?

Comment: If `#add_image_1669316654` is dynamic, then replace it with a generic `'input[type="file"]'`.

Comment: updated you code, please check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: after i upload image or add text, still `save design` button is not displaying.....

Comment: here is complete code, i will check your updated code now : https://pastebin.com/guR9p6hN

Comment: Just noticed, you are not using `$` but `jQuery` for your code. `$` doesn't seem to work on your website. Try updated code replacing the `$` symbol with `jQuery`.

Comment: sorry for that, i tried updated code, still `save design` button not displaying after i upload the image or add the text

Comment: I can't find my code in the debugger. The entire structure of your code is wrong. Try by yourself and let me know when you fix this.

Comment: also you code is reflecting in debugger also as here : http://prnt.sc/epgkpq , when you get free time, please check.....

Comment: Or make a fiddle and show your code in there, I can't debug through your entire website.

Comment: as this site includes lot of mixing of php and javascript code, its very difficult to create a fiddle, still i will try.....

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/78ff413a/54/) on how `input[type="file"]` works, and try this on your own.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Check edited code. Also you have to execute that code after your image has been uploaded.

Comment: i updated you code, its not working for me, can you please check [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html)

Answer (score 2):

add this code in css

```
#aitcg-control-panel{
    display:none;
}
```

Use the [.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) function of jQuery to detect the ajax and if it is to the following url's show it.

Check the following code

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "aitcg/ajax/addText/" || settings.url === "aitcg/ajax/addImage/" ) {
    jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show();
  }
});
```

use `jQuery` instead of `$` to select elements.

The above codes works fine when tested on browser.

If you are having any problem with the css,

Add the following instead of css.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").hide();
});
```

Comment: i followed your answer ,it successfully hiding `save design` , but now  `upload image or add text` buttons are not visible as in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html)

Comment: open both old and new links. on console, type `jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel");`. The old link give a perfect jQuery object. The second link is not. check it @user5348fh8y5

Comment: after i tried updated code, now `save design` is hiding,  but "save design" is not displaying after we `upload image or text`

Answer (score 2):

Hi well this might not be correct solution, but an example that works much similar to your `codes`, as in your `codes` you need an confirmation reply of `successful` upload of `text or image` to your server,

Here I have created two buttons `one .save_design` that needs to be `hidden` another `.add_text` or `.add_image`, now when your click `.add_text` a pop-up come-up for `uploading of text or image` which is just a div `#box1` over-here, this is what you need to `check`, I have included `textarea` into it to `check` if any `value` has been added to it `on blur` of textarea and using condition I could check yes that includes some value, so similarly you need to check that for your upload that it isn't null, if not then `.save-design fades-in`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".upload_text").on("click",function(){
  $("#box1").show();
});
$("#box1 > textarea").blur(function(){
 if($(this).val()){
   $(".save_design").show();
  }
  else{
    $(".save_design").hide();
     }  
 });
});
```

```css
#box1{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
#box1 > textarea{
  border:0px; 
  background:transparent;
  width:99%;
  height:98%;
  resize:none;
}
.upload_text{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
  background:orange;
  color:white;
  float:left;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
  margin-top:220px;
}
.save_design{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
  background:orange;
  color:white;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
  margin-top:220px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div class="upload_text">Add text</div>
<div class="save_design">Save Design</div>
```

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Hope this helps as a example to figure out issue.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 as I said this might work as an example, but you need to figure out what shall I get to put into condition, as because of textarea I have used blur eventListener but in your case it should be some kind of click.

Comment: updated your code with correct classes and ids,  in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5c.html) , it hide the button `save design` , now i need to display `save design` button after i `upload image or add text`, i am trying to follow your way of `onclick` instead of `blur eventListener` , if you get free time, please check the [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5c.html) once

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 I have checked and as soon we add text that get's visible in that phone section, as a suggestion you could select that div and using condition as soon as that get's visible make your save-design too visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139814/discussion-between-frnt-and-user5348fh8y5).

Comment: Hey @user5348fh8y5 It's okay don't be sorry, good you got solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using prototype JS and a normal `$(selector)` will not work like in jQuery.

You better use the vanilla JS queryselector

**Example**

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button[id^="submit-editorApply-"]')

//hide button
btn.style.display = "none";

//show button
btn.style.display = "block";
```

*Note: CSS selector is like that because of the random numbers appeared at the end of the button ID which will not going to work from a prototype `$()` method as it only accepts the exact element ID*

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 probably you're doing it wrong, update your post with your current codes

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 sir you only pasted the exact code I've given, you need to incorporate it into your codes, not exactly paste it, It's only an example, incorporating it from your code is much different, I also labeled the definition. Of course it will not hide the button since after display it none, a display of block will also trigger.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 you should know when will the image or text be remove and just simply execute the `btn.style.display = "none"; after confirmation`

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 not a problem, it's actually how you understand the logic, I just provided you of what you exactly need. I hope you learned from it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try using **delegate** instead change, like this:

$('#upload_field').on('**delegate**', function(){

if($(this).val() !== ""){

```
    $('#submit-editorApply-').show();
}
```

});

*credits to Danmoreng :)*